# c# aws create liveness detection start session

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core

currently working on a dotnet api solution need to verify the liveness by using Detecting face liveness API in aws services so I've created new session getting that session and want to start the liveness detection could not find any method in the SDK for start the session
and there is no suitable documentation specially for dotnet

```
await rekognitionClient.GetFaceLivenessSessionResultsAsync(new GetFaceLivenessSessionResultsRequest() { SessionId = sessionId });
```

Answer (score 2):

To perform the use case you describe, refer to this API reference doc for the .NET Rekognition API client:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Rekognition/MRekognitionGetFaceLivenessSessionResultsAsyncGetFaceLivenessSessionResultsRequestCancellationToken.html

As mentioned in this ref doc, this method requires the **sessionId** as input. You can create this using [CreateFaceLivenessSession](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Rekognition/MRekognitionCreateFaceLivenessSessionCreateFaceLivenessSessionRequest.html).

Comment: thanks for answer i can get the session id and can call the result as well the problem how i can send the video and or image i want to verify